# Is it possible to implement JsCast for a struct defined in Rust?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

The [documentation for JsCast](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/trait.JsCast.html) states that JsCast is implemented for any type defined inside a `#[wasm_bindgen]` `extern` block, i.e., any JS struct that has been imported into Rust. I would like to know if it is possible to implement JsCast for structs defined in Rust and exported to JS. As an example, consider the following code snippet:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
struct MyStruct;

let ms = MyStruct;
let msjsv: JsValue = ms.into(); // (1)
let ms = JsCast::unchecked_ref::<MyStruct>(&msjsv); // (2)
```

There are two things that I am confused about here. To start with, I would like to know what has happened after (1), e.g., I guess `MyStruct` still resides in the WebAssembly module's memory (in principle, I know it is a ZST), but I guess it's lifetime is now managed by JS...?

Secondly, I would like to know why (2) doesn't work, i.e., why `MyStruct` doesn't implement `JsCast`. It seems logical that I should be able to get a reference to `MyStruct` again. Should I manually implement `JsCast` here, or is there a reason why this hasn't been automatically provided?

Comment: https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2231

I don't really know wasm-bindgen, but if you need to convert back that way (e.g. parameters) it might be a better idea to use serde support? That is likely more expensive (as it bridges through JSON), but it works both ways.

Comment: Serde is not an option unfortunately when the `struct` in question contains `JsValue` types that cannot be serialized...

Answer (score 0):

I feel @Masklinn answered the second part of the question in the comments above, that is, this is a requested feature that is being discussed on Github but is not implemented yet.

For the first part of the question, regarding the use of `into` to convert a Rust `struct` into `JsValue`, I think I have found the answer from studying the output of wasm-bindgen.

What seems to happen is that the structure on the Rust side is moved onto the heap and a raw pointer to it is returned to wasm-bindgen's glue code, this raw pointer is stored inside a JS version of the struct. Once all references to the JS struct are gone, the garbage collector will free the memory, at which point, a hook is executed to also free the memory on the Rust side. In a sense, Rust has forgotten about this memory and relies on Javascript's garbage collector to free and trigger the deallocation at some point in the future.